# preg_match() expects parameter to be long string given

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am checking credit card fields to make sure they contain four digits each.

```
function creditcard ($creditCard1,$creditCard2,$creditCard3,$creditCard4)
{
    $regexp="/^[0-9]{4}$/";

    if (preg_match($regexp,$creditCard1,$creditCard2,$creditCard3,$creditCard4))//line 18
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert("Enter a valid credit card number.")</script>';
        return FALSE;
    }
}

    $creditCard1=$_POST['creditCard1'];
    $creditCard2=$_POST['creditCard2'];
    $creditCard3=$_POST['creditCard3'];
    $creditCard4=$_POST['creditCard4'];
    $creditcard=creditcard($creditCard1,$creditCard2,$creditCard3,$creditCard4);
```

I am getting this error.

```
Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SFASC2\aa.php on line 18
```

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong, thanks. There are many questions like this, but none giving me  the solution.. and I've been hitting my head against a wall, no doubt overlooking the obvious.

Comment: Have a look at the [reference page of `preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match), especially the function’s parameters.

Comment: You're handling actual credit cards? That's scary. Are you aware of all the security requirements related to credit cards?

Comment: Oh, calm down. If you had said that this is an assignment, there would be no issue. Quite a few people actually try to handle real sensitive data with this much experience, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) check only one subject at a time.

Try following code:

```
function creditcard($nums)
{
    $regexp="/^[0-9]{4}$/";

    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
        if (! preg_match($regexp, $nums[$i]))
            return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}

$creditCard1 = $_POST['creditCard1'];
$creditCard2 = $_POST['creditCard2'];
$creditCard3 = $_POST['creditCard3'];
$creditCard4 = $_POST['creditCard4'];

$ok = creditcard([$creditCard1, $creditCard2, $creditCard3, $creditCard4]);
if (! $ok)
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Enter a valid credit card number.")</script>';
```

Comment: @Skippy, See the signature of preg_match : `int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )`. It take only one subject.

Answer (score 4):

Its better to use [**preg_grep**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) instead of `preg_match` for this use-case since you're applying a single regex against an array of inputs. Main benefit with use of `preg_grep` is that you can avoid looping the input. Consider below code:

```
function creditcard($arr) {
    static $re="/^\d{4}$/";
    return (preg_grep($re, $arr) === $nums);
}

$result = creditcard(['5423', '1234', '1234', '1234']);
// returns true
$result = creditcard(['5423', 'A234', '1234', '1234']);
// returns false
```

*PS: I declared `$re` as `static` since that variable should be declared & initialized once only.*